# When rendering through a helper function I get: "Objects are not valid as a React child" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a small project in React Native. I have noticed a weird situation whereby when I render a list through a helper function, I get the eponymous error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child

Now this error normally means that I am trying to render an object, which is not the case. I will paste two snippets of code. The first one is how I render the data through a helper function, resulting through an error. The second snippet is how I render the data directly in the `render()` method and working successfully.

**Snippet #1:** Rendering through helper function `renderUsers()` -> does not work

```
  renderUsers = async () => {
    return this.props.userList.map(
      ({ instructions, address, createdDate, _id }) => (
        <Card
          title={`${moment(createdDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}`}
          key={_id}
        >
          <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>{instructions}.</Text>
          <Button backgroundColor="#03A9F4" title="Ready to Help!" />
        </Card>
      )
    );
  };
  ...
  render() {
    return this.props.isFetchingUsers ? null : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.renderUsers()}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**Snippet #2:** Rendering directly inside `render()` function -> works OK

```
  render() {
    return this.props.isFetchingUsers ? null : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.props.userList.map(
            ({ instructions, address, createdDate, _id }) => (
              <Card
                title={`${moment(createdDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}`}
                key={_id}
              >
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>{instructions}.</Text>
                <Button backgroundColor="#03A9F4" title="Ready to Help!" />
              </Card>
            )
          )}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Why do you define `renderUsers` async ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet 1 should be like this.

```
renderUsers = () => {
return this.props.userList.map(
  ({ instructions, address, createdDate, _id }) => (
    <Card
      title={`${moment(createdDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}`}
      key={_id}
    >
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>{instructions}.</Text>
      <Button backgroundColor="#03A9F4" title="Ready to Help!" />
    </Card>
  )
);
};
...
render() {
  return this.props.isFetchingUsers ? null : (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <ScrollView>
      {this.renderUsers()}
     </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You need to remove the keyword `async`

Answer (score 2):

The async function will return Promise Object, which is not supposed to be a React child.

But you no need `async` function for Array map.

If you want to render something `asynchronously` try updating state by `this.setState` and render it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return null in render method!

You should render an element like this:

```
  render() {
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
        { 
          (!this.props.isFetchingUsers && this.props.userList) &&
          this.renderUsers()
        }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  }
```

then remove the keyword `async` from `renderUsers` method.